# Google detecting crawl errors on URLs that don't exist or are misconfigured

Tags: web-crawler, google-search-console

We're seeing a sharp increase in 500 errors, and Google Webmaster Tools is showing URLs that have HTML in them... obviously, we don't have URLs with HTML in them, so I'm wondering how Googlebot is finding and listing these.  An example would be a url that contains the following:

http://www.prweekus.com/asia/news/article/419711/%3Cspan

(note the html span tag at the end of the url ... why would this be there?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that you have inbound links from another site which have misformed links into your site. You might be able to see these in the "Links to your Site" under the "Search Traffic"  section of your Google Webmaster Tool Site Dashboard.